# Which path should I use to upload to Team-Folders in Dropbox

Tags: swift, dropbox, swiftydropbox

We recently switched from Dropbox to Dropbox Business. Since then I uploaded files via the Dropbox API for Swift (SwiftyDropbox) only using the path where the file was saved.

I can't just change the path because it just uploads to the normal personal Dropbox. But now I am wondering how to access Teamfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading the Namespace Guide for information on how Business accounts are structured and how to access team spaces:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/namespace-guide

In the SwiftyDropbox library in particular, you can set the 'Dropbox-API-Path-Root' header by passing in a [`PathRoot`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/Common/PathRoot.html) as the `pathRoot` parameter when constructing your `DropboxClient`.